# Por que funções normais não podem tem argumentos "auto" se os "lambda expressions" podem em C++?

Tags: c++, funções, expressões-lambda

Percebi que os "*lambda expressions*" aceitam argumentos do tipo `auto`. Por exemplo:

```
auto add = [](const auto& x, const auto& y) 
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Então fui tentar com funções normais, mas não deu certo:

```
auto add(const auto& x, const auto& y)
{
    return x + y; // Não compila
}
```

Alguém poderia me explicar o porquê disso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, `auto` para parâmetros de lambdas existe para cobrir o fato de que não há como especificar tipos genéricos usando `template`. Mas isso foi até [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), pois isso mudou em [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), com a possibilidade de [especificá-los dentro da lambda](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0428r1.pdf):

```
auto sum = []<typename T, typename U>(T a, U b) { return a + b; };
```

Ainda em [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), a funcionalidade [c++-concepts](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-concepts) entrou na linguagem, e junto veio a possibilidade de declarar funções normais com a sintaxe do `auto`:

```
auto square(auto a, auto b) -> decltype(a + b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Alternativamente, é possível escrever a mesma função acima usando [c++templates](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2btemplates):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto sum(T a, U b) -> decltype(a + b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso é uma questão de lógica. Por que, por exemplo, as funções tem o retorno definido:

```
int main(){

    //Na main o retorno é de um inteiro, se o programa executar normalmente retorna 0.
    auto v1 = 56; //O auto é um tipo indefinido, tem que ser inicializada para saber qual tipo.

    return 0; 
}
```

Nesse exemplo que você fez em sua pergunta.

```
auto add(const auto& x, const auto& y)
{
    return x + y; //não compila porque o auto é indefinido então o compilador não vai saber qual
    //é o retorno. Mesmo usando em parâmetros também não dá certo
} 

auto add = [](const auto& x, const auto& y) //Já aqui nessa parte ele aceita.
{
    //Uma parte porque ela é inicializada como uma função.
    //A outra em forma de função não lambda não acontece pois o compilador não irá saber se é 
    //um retorno, por exemplo, int, double, float, char, const char* entre outros.
    return x + y;
}
```

Já em um template:

```
template <typename in, typename out> out func(in _valor){
    //...
    //Podemos usar o template em retorno e em entrada pois quando for chamar
    //indicaremos o tipo a cada typename como float para entrada e int para saída.
}
```