# O que significa o operador [&] antes de uma função sem nome?

Tags: c++, funções, expressões-lambda, sintaxe, closures

Estou tentando ler o código de uma função que está definida assim:

```
auto loop = [&](int ntensor, char** data, const int64_t* strides, int64_t n) {
...
  };
```

O que significa o `[&]` antes da função?

Comment: Isso lembra notação lambda do C++, como pode ser vista à semelhança com o trecho de código nesta pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325704/64969

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isto não é bem uma função. Tecnicamente é, mas é uma função anônima, você parece saber aproximadamente, a maioria sequer verá isso como uma função.

Significa que todas as variáveis capturadas por esta possível [clausura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) serão capturadas como referências. Isso significa que os valores delas não serão copiados para junto da sua função *lambda*, mas apenas uma referência para elas existirá dentro da função e obviamente estas variáveis precisarão sobreviver pelo menos enquanto sua *lambda* existir.

Isto estabelece um padrão para todas variáveis capturadas a não ser que alguma seja especificada de forma diferente.

Isto se faz necessário porque em capturas nem sempre queremos o valor da mesma forma que eles foram declaradas.

Note que eu não estou falando dos parâmetros, estou falando de possíveis variáveis usadas dentro da sua função que não foram declaradas dentro dela (parâmetros são locais a ela), e obviamente foram declaradas no função onde esta *lambda* foi escrita ou em escopo anterior, mas elas devem estar no [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101). Não posso dizer se existe alguma porque justamente o corpo dela foi omitido (e idealmente todo o contexto mostraria melhor). Algo assim:

```
void Teste() {
    int i = 1;
    auto loop = [&](int ntensor, char** data, const int64_t* strides, int64_t n) {
        ...
        //faz algo com i aqui e este será uma referência para o i declarado antes
        ...
    };
    //faz algo com loop aqui, possivelmente passar como argumento para outra função
}
```

Já assim haverá uma cópia do valor de `i` e nenhuma referência para ela:

```
void Teste() {
    int i = 1;
    auto loop = [=](int ntensor, char** data, const int64_t* strides, int64_t n) {
        ...
        //faz algo com i aqui (neste exemplo eu sei que é 1, poderia ser outro valor)
        ...
    };
    //faz algo com loop aqui, possivelmente passar como argumento para outra função
}
```

Se não tivesse esse `i` (por exemplo) dentro não seria uma clausura e por isso não haveria captura de variáveis e não faria diferença como a captura foi declarada.

Se nenhuma variável for capturada por não usar nenhuma declarada fora do escopo da *lambda* então não muda nada.

Um exemplo funcional:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    auto loop = [=]() { cout << i; }; //não pode fazer o incremento aqui
    loop();
    auto loop2 = [&]() { cout << i++; };
    loop2();
    cout << i;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6S36fF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mfgzcklw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Closure.cpp).

Em C++ é possível dizer como quer que cada variável seja capturada, mas o mais comum é usar o padrão ou todas por referência. Mas sempre você terá que cuidar do tempo de vida da variável, e isso é uma das coisas mais complicadas se não for por valor, o que faz, em alguns casos, sentir a falta de um *garbage collector*.

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).